# How can I show UTC time on x axis of matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, datetime, matplotlib

I've tried several solutions, but I think I'm not really grasping what format matplotlib wants.

I want my x axis to go from the epoch time I'm given, to UTC time shown in a format similar to

```
8:20pm
```

I only need the hour, minute, and am/pm.

**The Code**

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import datetime

x = []
y = []

with open('myCSVfile.csv','r') as csvFile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        # Removing everything after . in epoch time.
        epochTime = row[0].split('.', 1)[0]
        dateTime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(float(epochTime)))
        newDateTime = dates.datestr2num(dateTime)
        x.append(newDateTime)
        # Removing everything after . in seconds
        deltaTime = row[1].split('.', 1)[0]
        y.append(deltaTime)
plt.plot_date(x,y, label="blah")

plt.xticks( rotation=25 )
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('deltaTime')
plt.title('plot title')
```

**The Output**

The x axis is outputting this format

```
11-28 20
```

**CSV File**

header="epoch time", "seconds"

```
1506113708.561633531,1171.27425957
1506114083.970948133,1382.68399167
1506131461.369560006,403.082466364
1506129829.157526598,588.869942665
1506132085.925451203,303.638436317
```

Comment: In this case you would want to use `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%I:%M %p")` to get the desired format.

Comment: I appreciate the link to the other question, but I still don't quite understand how I'm supposed to use the matplotlib DateFormatter.  The add_subplot isn't something that I've needed before. (sorry hit return too soon, still editing)

Comment: `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%I:%M %p"))`

Comment: [Date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/date.html?highlight=time%20tick%20labels)

Comment: Matplotlib understands Python datetime objects. You can simplify your for loop: `epochTime, seconds = row; x.append(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(epochTime)));   deltaTime = int(float(seconds));  y.append(deltaTime)`

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  Even though it's a duplicate, I learned a lot.